# How to delete all my replies on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I understand how to delete my YouTube comments, but is there a way to bulk delete all the replies I have made at all video sites without having to return to each individual site?

Comment: You might be able to do something with the YouTube API. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to programmatically remove comments, see this answer at Stack Overflow: "[Remove a comment using the youtube data api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40852092/3648282)", but the quota will limit you to ~200/day.

Here is their help:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete

You can also go to this webpage: https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history and manually delete the ones you want, as many as you want, fairly quickly (and likely more than 10/minute, if you have patience).

[image: YouTube Comments]